# Get filter Data from previous Data set in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one Query:

```sql
    campaignData = Event
      .where(campaign_id: Campaign.where(customer_id: params[:customer_id]))
      .where('scheduled >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY')
      .limit('30')
```

Which I use to show data on html.
Now I use some filter that should be filter data from the previous 30 data. as I use limit(30)
data are more than one million.

filter:

```sql
    if !params[:channel].blank?
      campaignData = campaignData.where(channel: params[:channel])
    end

    if !params[:offerType].blank?
      campaignData = campaignData.where(offerType: params[:offerType])
    end
```

It giving me another set of 30 result which I not required. It should filter from the previous 30 data set.

can't use loop because

I am using

```sql
    campaignData = campaignData.where(audienceQuery)
```

Where audienceQuery is a query pass from front end using `QueryBuilder`. Which is the most important.

Thanks in advance.

We can use Inner join, run another query then merge with this.
tried many approaches but unable to filter data from the dataset.

Comment: do you want to filter channel and offer_type on your limited(30) result?
or you want filter channel and offer_type on whole dataset?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have exact 30 records on response (don't worry about milions of records. this query will handled by database and will not have overhead if you define correct indexes) try this:

```
campaignData = Event
      .where(campaign_id: Campaign.where(customer_id: params[:customer_id]))
      .where('scheduled >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY')

if !params[:channel].blank?
  campaignData = campaignData.where(channel: params[:channel])
end

if !params[:offerType].blank?
  campaignData = campaignData.where(offerType: params[:offerType])
end

campaignData = campaignData.limit('30')
```

if you want to apply filter after limitation try this:

```
if !params[:channel].blank?
  campaignData = campaignData.select{ |cd| cd.channel == params[:channel] }
end

if !params[:offerType].blank?
  campaignData = campaignData.select{ |cd| cd.offerType == params[:offerType] }
end
```

Comment: I need to fire `campaignData = campaignData.where(audienceQuery)` also where audienceQuery is a query.

Comment: Sorry, but this will provide 30 results but not filter that.

Comment: can you add `.to_sql` at the end of query and give me string result ?

Comment: SELECT  id, name FROM `event` WHERE `event`.`campaign_id` IN (SELECT `tc_campaigns`.`id` FROM `campaigns` WHERE `campaigns`.`customer_id` = 1) AND (scheduled >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND `events`.`channel` = 'S' AND (country IN('IN', 'UK')) LIMIT 30

where `S` = `channel` and `country IN('IN', 'UK')` = `audienceQuery `

Comment: active record automatically prevent app from SQL injection and you shouldn't pass audienceQuery as raw query
also, use limit at the end of the query as a separate command to work correctly `campaignData = campaignData.limit('30')`

Comment: When I don't pass any params Show record as total 30. Then provide some filters so I required to filter from those only. I gave a query builder by which it creates a query any filter result and audienceQuery which is a feature of the system so we required.